# Move image over another image in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to move image over the other image in WPF.

But when I move the image1 , It is displaying below the image2 instead of above the image2.

**Mainwindow.xaml**

```
  <Image x:Name="imgPattern1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="170" Margin="523,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="248"
            PreviewMouseDown="imgPattern_PreviewMouseDown"
            PreviewMouseUp="imgPattern_PreviewMouseUp"
            PreviewMouseMove="imgPattern_PreviewMouseMove"
               >
            <Image.Style>
                <Style TargetType="Image">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                            <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.5" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </Image.Style>
        </Image>

<Image x:Name="imgPattern2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="170" Margin="523,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="248"/>
```

[image]

I want to move pattern1 to move over pattern2

Thanks in  advance

Comment: User attached property called `Canvas.ZIndex`. Make sure that your second image has bigger value than the first one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use attached property called [Canvas.ZIndex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.canvas.zindex%28v=vs.95%29.aspx). Make sure that your second image has bigger value than the first one. Or simply exchange the images in your xaml layout so your second image becomes the first one.

```
  <Image x:Name="imgPattern1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="170" Margin="523,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="248"
            PreviewMouseDown="imgPattern_PreviewMouseDown"
            PreviewMouseUp="imgPattern_PreviewMouseUp"
            PreviewMouseMove="imgPattern_PreviewMouseMove"
               >
            <Image.Style>
                <Style TargetType="Image">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                            <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.5" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </Image.Style>
        </Image>

<Image x:Name="imgPattern2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="170" Margin="523,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="248" Canvas.ZIndex=2/>
```

Comment: That's it. Additionally, I would say that is safer (to avoid surprises), when you set ZIndex to one element, to set it also to (every) other element in the same scope.

Comment: In WPF, the property is [`Panel.ZIndex`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.panel.zindex.aspx) (in contrast to the Silverlight `Canvas.ZIndex` property).

Answer (score 0):

Without explicitly specifying  a `ZIndex`, the order in which child elements are drawn is determined by the order in which they are added to their common container. The first element is drawn first, the last one last.

So Instead of setting a `ZIndex` you might just change the order of the Image controls:

```
<Image x:Name="imgPattern2" ... />
<Image x:Name="imgPattern1" ... />
```

Now `imgPattern1` is drawn above `imgPattern2`.